# How come a prompt is not popping up? I need help setting a variable to input from a prompt

Tags: javascript, if-statement, prompt

```
var x = prompt("What is your name").toLowerCase();
{
if x = "ernest" {
document.write("Yooo");
}
else {
document.write("loser");
}
```

This is javascript. I need help assigning the input from the prompt to a variable.

Comment: That is not JS ...

Comment: 1. The opening curly brace on line 2 is invalid. 2. `if x = ...`: you need parentheses surrounding a condition, and that is an assignment and not a condition (use comparison operators)

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is wrong, try this:

```
if (x === "ernest"){
  document.write("Yooo");
} else {
  document.write("loser");
}
```

Note that this: `x = "ernest"` is an assignment. You are assigning "ernest" to x.

But this: `x == "ernest"`is a comparition. You are comparing if "ernest" is the value of x.

And even better: `x === "ernest"`. You are comparing if "ernest" is a string and is the value of x (it compares both value and type).

`=` is the assignment operator

`==`  is the comparision operator

`===` is the strict comparision operator

Check the docs [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp)

Besides, using `document.write()` is a bad practice, because it will overwrite your whole document. If you are using it only for practicing it's OK, but not recommended in a real world project.